# File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: jinja2, jsondecodeerror

I am getting error running below in jinja.

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

"fc_key": {{ '"'+metadata['config_group']|string+'"' if metadata['config_group'] is not none else '""' }},
"fc_value": {{ inputs['data'] | replace("'", '"')}}

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) .

Can someone please help

Comment: Where's the code you were executing?  The error is quite clear -- you tried to JSON decode a value that was `None`.